# invertible matrix and polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

The exercise is: If A is an invertible matrix then there is a polynomial $p(t)\in \mathbb{K}[t]$ that $A^{-1}=p(A)$.

I've tried to think that, if A is invertible, then the characteristic polynomial has the form $p_A(t)=t^n+\ldots+a_1t+(-1)^n\det(A)$, with $\det(A)\neq 0$. So, the minimal polynomial is something like $m_A(t)=t^n+\ldots+ b_0$, with $b_0\neq 0$. I am trying do some modification in $m_A$ to conclude the exercise. Some type?

Comment: Take a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497540/proving-the-inverse-of-a-matrix-as-a-polynomial-of-matrices

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem?

Comment: thanks, guys!!!